# call-interactively: Text is read-only: "Type `e' to edit property"

Tags: emacs, org-mode, readonly

I'm working in org-mode, and while trying to delete some blank lines, I get the error message

```
call-interactively: Text is read-only: "Type `e' to edit property"
```

I'm not using read-only mode. I am unable to delete the blank lines but I am able to type elsewhere in the buffer.

Comment: Consider providing more context. Just what is the text, where is your cursor when you try to delete the lines, and what key(s) do you use to try to delete them - etc. A better question helps people help you more.

Comment: It sounds very much as if there is a read-only text property associated with those lines. What happens when you type `e` ?

Comment: And you can use `C-u C-x =` to see what text properties are at the cursor position.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For me the problem occurred when I was had the buffer in `column view` and didn't press `q` to quit.

See https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2009-03/msg00151.html for more details.

Comment: Maybe worth adding that if that is the case, the problem can be fixed by changing back to the colum view and then pressing `q` to exit.

Answer (score 4):

`M-x org-columns-quit RET`

This command will **remove the column overlays** and in this way exit column editing.

More at  [7.5.2 Using column view](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Using-column-view.html)

Answer (score 3):

Saving the file, killing the buffer, and revisiting the file cleared up the problem for me.